# Tcl How to determine namespace of the importer from the imported routine

Tags: import, namespaces, tcl

I am wrestling with trying to implement a simple object-oriented like system in Tcl 8.4.18.  I've looked at Itcl, stooops, XOTtcl, etc... and haven't decided if I want to use them, especially if I can do it another simple way.  Anyway, lets says I have a namespace

```
namespace eval Object {
    namespace export setvar

    proc setvar { model name value } {
        set ${model}::${name} $value
    }
}
```

and then I "subclass" if with another namespace

```
namespace eval Model {
    namespace import ::Object::*
    variable foo 0
}
```

I can set the variable like this

```
Model::setvar Model foo 2
puts $Model::foo
```

which outputs "2".  However, I would like to simplify the code so that the routine "setvar" from the Object namespace can determine that it is being called from the "Model" namespace.  Something like this:

```
proc setvar { name value } {
    set myspace [namespace current]
    set ${namespace}::${name} $value
}
```

and then call it like

```
Model::setvar foo 2
```

but that doesn't work because [namespace current] returns "::Object" and not "::Model".  According to the documentation that is because the importation just makes a reference back to the Object namespace.

The reason to use the routine setvar is to try and implement a variable override so that I can use foo from Model if it exists, otherwise get it from Object.

Are there any other methods to do this?  Or should I just use one of the other tools?

Thanks

Comment: Ah, the usual thing, first you write your own OO system in Tcl ;-). The Tcl 8.4.18 version is pretty old, a newer one might make a few things easier (especially the 8.6 betas which have a built in OO system which you might want to study). I am pretty sure what you try to do is possible, but it will probably not be fast. The simplest way might be to override 'namespace import' and let it create aliases instead of true imports. Or best might be the use of the namespace command resolvers, but those are not available in 8.4.

Comment: The OO system in 8.6 is also available as an extension for 8.5.

Comment: Be aware that object systems are _difficult_ to get right. You can do a lot, but you hit a wall unless you're prepared to do a significant amount of work.

Comment: Thanks, it appears I am traveling a well worn route.  I think I only need a small subset true OO programming, so namespace might be sufficient for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you are looking for is *tricky*, but possible to do (the key is `namespace which`):

```
proc setvar { name value } {
    set cmdnameScript [list namespace which [lindex [info level 0] 0]]
    set myspace [namespace qualifiers [uplevel 1 $cmdnameScript]]]
    set ${myspace}::${name} $value
}
```

If you're using 8.5 (or later), consider replacing that last `set` with:

```
namespace upvar $myspace $name var
set var $value
```

It's a lot easier to work with once things start to get complicated. Failing that, do use `upvar` (almost as easy to work with, not as fast, portable back as far as Tcl 8.0):

```
upvar 0 ${myspace}::$name var
set var $value
```

Comment: (FWIW, I tested this in 8.4.7 — except for the `namespace upvar` part — so I really think it should work for you.)

Comment: Wow, consider my mind blown.  I had to go read the manual to understand this just a little bit.  Thank you.  Maybe sometime soon we will upgrade to the newer Tcl, but right now I am stuck with 8.4.